# How do I get dark toolbars in gtkmm?

Tags: application-development

How do I get dark toolbars in gtkmm like in gedit or system settings? I can only seem to find how to do it in pyGTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that you just need to map the Python GTK functions to GTKMM. The code in Python GTK is:

```
context = self.toolbar.get_style_context()
context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)
```

So you just need to find the equivilent of `get_style_context()` and `add_class()` and the `Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR` constant.

Comment: I don't know why i didn't find this before: [link](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1StyleContext.html)

Comment: This is the desired gtkmm equivelent: `Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> sc = toolbar.get_style_context();    sc->add_class("primary-toolbar");`